# Find an expected value and variance

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I hope that formulation is clear enough.

Assume we have a traditional dice $\omega_1 = \{1, ..., 6\}$, and a coin $\omega_2=\{\mathbf{head}, \mathbf{tail}\}$.
Dice is rolled once, we then toss the coin $N$ times, where $N$ — the number on the dice we have got after it was rolled. Find expected value and variance of $\mathbf{tail}$.

...

$$E\space\{x\} = \sum_{i=1}^{6} \frac{1}{6}P_i = \frac{21}{6}$$
$$E\space\{y\} = \frac{21}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{12} = \frac{21}{12}$$
$$P(y\leq6)=1$$
$$P(y>5)=P(x=6) \cdot (\frac{1}{2})^6 = \frac{1}{6} \cdot\frac{1}{64}$$
$$P(y=6)=P(y>5)$$
$$P(y=5)=\frac{1}{6} \cdot (\frac{1}{2})^5 + \frac{1}{6} \cdot (\frac{1}{2})^5 \cdot C_6^5 \cdot\frac{1}{2}$$

Should conditional probability be introduced here? How should it be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y$ be your dice roll. Let $X_1,...,X_6$ be coin tosses and finally, let $T$ be the number of tails.

We then have $\mathbb E[T] = \mathbb E [ \mathbb E[T|Y]]$

Now, note that $T = \sum_{k=1}^Y X_k$ and since $Y$ is discrete, we only need to condition on events $Y=n$.

So take any $n \in \{1,...,6\}$

$$\mathbb E [ \sum_{k=1}^Y X_k | Y= n ]  = \mathbb E [ \sum_{k=1}^n X_k | Y=n] = \frac{\mathbb E[\sum_{k=1}^n X_k \cdot \chi_{_{Y=n}}]}{\mathbb P(Y=n)}$$

Now, since every $X_k$, $k \in \{1,...,6\}$ is independent of $Y$, so is $\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ independent of $\chi_{_{Y=n}}$ (note our sum is not random anymore).

So we have:  $$\mathbb E[T|Y=n] = \frac{\mathbb E[\sum_{k=1}^n X_k] \mathbb P(Y=n)}{\mathbb P(Y=n)} = \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb E[X_k] = \frac{n}{2}$$.

So $\mathbb E[T|Y] = \frac{Y}{2}$, and we have $\mathbb E[T] = \mathbb E[\mathbb E[T|Y] ] = \frac{1}{2} \mathbb E[Y] = \frac{7}{4}$

Now looking at variance, we need to find $\mathbb E[T^2]$, since $(\mathbb E[T])^2= \frac{41}{16} $

Again, take any $n \in \{1,...,6\}$ and due to independence, we have: $$\mathbb E[T^2 ] = \mathbb E[ \mathbb E[T^2|Y=n] = \mathbb E[\mathbb E[ (\sum_{k=1}^n X_k)^2 | Y= n ]] = \mathbb E[\mathbb E[ \sum_{k=1}^n X_k^2 + 2 \sum_{1 \le i <j \le n} X_iX_j] ] $$

Now aplly linearity, and we get:

$\mathbb E[\sum_{k=1}^n X_k^2] = \frac{n}{2} $ , $$\mathbb E[ 2\sum_{1 \le i < j \le n} X_iX_j] = 2\sum_{1 \le i < j \le n} \mathbb E[X_iX_j] = 2 {n \choose 2} \mathbb E[X_iX_j] = \frac{1}{2} {n \choose 2} = \frac{1}{4}(n^2 - n) $$

So $\mathbb E[T^2] = \mathbb E[ \mathbb E[T^2 | Y ] = \mathbb E[ \frac{Y}{2} + \frac{Y^2-Y}{4}] = \frac{1}{4} \mathbb E[Y + Y^2] = \frac{1}{4}(\frac{7}{2}+ \frac{1+4+9+16+25+36}{6}) = \frac{14}{16} + \frac{91}{24}$

So now $Var(Y) = \mathbb E[T^2] - (\mathbb E[T])^2 = \frac{14}{16} + \frac{91}{24} - \frac{49}{16} = \frac{91}{24} - \frac{35}{16} = \frac{182 - 105}{48} = \frac{77}{48} $

Comment: Thank you so much. $\chi$ here stays for $P(Y=n)$?

Comment: $\chi$ stands for indicator function, that is $\chi_{_{Y=n}}(\omega) = 1$ if and only if $Y(\omega) = n$

Comment: To be more precise, $\mathbb E[\chi_{_{Y=n}}] = \mathbb P(Y=n)$